# How can i schedule a apex job on Daily basis using "Schedule Apex" button under Develop->Apex Classes section

Tags: scheduled-apex

I want to schedule a job on daily basis so can anyone explain how can i do that using UI option? I don't want to do that using code. I just want to use "Schedule Apex" option available under App Setup -> Develop -> Apex classes.

Comment: Is there something in particular you're confused about?  It seems like you already know what to do ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1) Define a class that implements the schedulable interface

Step 2) Click the 'Schedule Apex' button and enter the details.